# How to create an empty file in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I want to create an empty file or do nothing if a file already exists. Truncating an existing file would be fine too.

Currently I do this:

```
exec touch file/name.txt
```

This works, but depends on an external command and will only work on UNIX-y OS. Is there a way to do the same that is both *concise* and *portable*?

Comment: `close [open file/name.txt w]`

Comment: Or [`fileutil::touch`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.md#21) for fancier options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open a file for writing and immediately close it:

Create or truncate (The result is always an empty file):

```
close [open file/name.txt w]
```

Create or do nothing (thanks, Donal Fellows):

```
close [open file/name.txt a]
```

- [open](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/open.html)
- [close](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/close.html)

Thanks to Shawn for this suggestion.

Comment: To touch a file without truncating it, use the `a` mode instead of `w`.